# How can I check the ID of a pandas data frame in another data frame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Hello I have the following Data Frame:

```
df = 
ID   Value
a     45
b     3
c     10
```

And another dataframe with the numeric ID of each value

```
df1 =

ID    ID_n
a      3
b      35
c      0
d      7
e      1
```

I would like to have a new column in `df` with the numeric `ID`, so:

```
df = 
ID   Value  ID_n
a     45     3
b     3      35 
c     10     0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas merge:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'Value': [45, 3, 10]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'ID_n': [3, 35, 0, 7, 1],
})

df1.set_index(['ID'], drop=False, inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['ID'], drop=False, inplace=True)

print pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID", how='left')
```

output:

```
  ID  Value  ID_n
0  a     45     3
1  b      3    35
2  c     10     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `join()`,

```
In [14]: df1.join(df2)
Out[14]: 
    Value  ID_n
ID             
a      45     3
b       3    35
c      10     0
```

If you want index to be numeric you could reset_index(),

```
In [17]: df1.join(df2).reset_index()
Out[17]: 
  ID  Value  ID_n
0  a     45     3
1  b      3    35
2  c     10     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single operation.  `join` works on the index, which you don't appear to have set. Just set the index to `ID`, join `df` after also setting its index to `ID`, and then reset your index to return your original dataframe with the new column added.

```
>>> df.set_index('ID').join(df1.set_index('ID')).reset_index()
  ID  Value  ID_n
0  a     45     3
1  b      3    35
2  c     10     0
```

Also, because you don't do an inplace `set_index` on `df1`, its structure remains the same (i.e. you don't change its indexing).